# How to fix "HA is not enabled" error in simple hdfs HA cluster

Tags: docker, hdfs, hadoop2

I have training task to build **HA cluster** with 2 docker containers with **hdfs**. I created 2 docker containers from image "*sequenceiq/hadoop-docker*" (which has hadoop version 2.7.0). I try to implement "**shared storage**" architecture (according to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html). Instead of nfs shared folder I use /volume folder which is a volume from my docker mounted into both my containers during run command. Both containers has write/read permissions on /volume. I made configurations in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml. Also I set up passwordless access via ssh between both containers. But "`$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs namenode -format`" command fails with such messages:

```
19/07/31 11:50:14 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
19/07/31 11:50:14 WARN namenode.FSNamesystem: Configured NNs:

19/07/31 11:50:14 ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: Invalid configuration: a shared edits dir must not be specified if HA is not enabled.
```

And the same result on running "`$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`"
It seems like there is a mistake in **nn1** and **nn2** namenode aliases configuration (empty string after "Configured NNs:"). But I made configs according to tutorial!
Please help me to make HA Enabled in my hdfs cluster!

Here is core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
```

and hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservice</name>
        <value>mycluster</value>
    </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.myclaster</name>
     <value>nn1,nn2</value>
  </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/home/hadoop/local_nn_dir</value>
    </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
    <value>nn1.mycluster.com:8020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
    <value>nn2.mycluster.com:8020</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name>
     <value>nn1.mycluster.com:50070</value>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name>
     <value>nn2.mycluster.com:50070</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
    <value>file:///volume</value>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/hadoop/dn_dir</value>
</property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Both docker containers has identical config xml files but "*nn1.mycluster.com*" and "*nn2.mycluster.com*" configured in */etc/hosts* to point to localhost and to another docker container respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem. There was 2 typos in hdfs-site.xml:
"`dfs.nameservice`" instead of "`dfs.nameservices`" and "`dfs.ha.namenodes.myclaster`" instead of "`dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster`".
Сonclusion: Configs accuracy is first and foremost!